# Из поля в переменную

Tags: php, html, javascript

Как записать в переменную информацию из такого поля?

```
 <input name="time" type="text" size="10">
```

Kexit два варианта в php и js/

Comment: как данные передаваться будут? POST GET быть может ajax используете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//index.html
<form action="get_value.php" method="get">
<input name="time" type="text" size="10">
<input type="submit" value="Получить значение">
</form>

//get_value.php
<?php
$value = $_GET['time'];
echo $value;
?>

    //javascript
<input name="time" type="text" size="10" id="time">
    <script>
    function asd(){
       var value = document.getElementById('time').value;
    alert(value);
    }
    </script>
```